# why is the main window not enabled when the load event is in the prism framework

Tags: wpf

xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="ZPC.Phone.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZPC.Phone"
        WindowStyle="None"
        x:Name="WindowMain"
        xmlns:event="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="    #F5F5F5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="780" Width="1280">
    <event:Interaction.Triggers>
        <event:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandLoaded}"/>
        </event:EventTrigger>
    </event:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs Code:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: BindableBase, INavigationAware, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand CommandLoaded { get; set; }
  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    CommandLoaded = new CommandBase(new Action<object>((e) =>
    {

    }));
  }
}
```

questions：
I use event and load "CommandLoaded" in the constructor, and then the main form state will not be enabled，Why？thank you

Comment: Have you actually put a line of code in your CommandLoaded code to verify that it gets hit or not?  Because when I try this, it works for me.  My breakpoint gets hit.  More to the point, let me just say that I think EventToCommand is one of the biggest wastes of your time there is.  It's made to appeal to MVVM purists but it doesn't really save you anything.  Just write yourself a simple event handler for the loaded event and be done with it.   Code-behind is not evil.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for your reply. I tested it. Breakpoints are hit。I have a reason to use event this way